# Segments prevent the display of tooltips of markers in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I try to create a plot in R using plotly. This plot consists of several elements, i.e. segments and markers. Segments do not display tooltips and markers do display tooltips.

Each marker is located exactly at the end of a segment which results in the following problem. Marker tooltips are generally displayed, but not in the area where segment tooltips would have been shown (which are suppressed). Hence, the center of the marker does not display a tooltip.

How can I modify my code so that the marker tooltip is displayed in the whole area without that 'blind spot' from the segment?

plotly_4.7.1
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

```
#install.packages("plotly")
library("plotly")

p <- plot_ly()
p <- add_segments(p, x = 1, y = 1, xend = 1, yend = 0,
                  line = list(color = "red", layer="below"),
                  hoverinfo="none"
)
p <- add_markers(p, x = 1, y = 1, 
                 marker=list(size = 10, color = "blue", layer="above"),
                 hoverinfo="text", hovertext="here!", hoveron="points+fills"
)
p
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'whole area'? Everything to the left of the red line or the red line itself?

Comment: I mean that the center of the marker and the area around this point does not display a tooltip.